# If Picture A is displayed then Text A must be entered else LABEL say Wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'm sorry if this seems stupid to you but I need help creating something like this:

If Picture A is displayed in an UIImageView the UITextfield has to be PictureA-description.

So let's say a picture of the USA flag is displayed.  The user needs to enter USA to get to next view otherwise the UILabel will say "Wrong".

When I tried with:

```
@implementation ViewController

 -(IBAction)ButtonTouched:(id)sender
 {
     [self.inputfield resignFirstResponder];

     if (_inputfield.text isEqualtoString @"USA") //BUT IT SAYS PARSE ISSUE EXPECTED')'
{
    __errorlabel.text = @"Correct";
    sleep(1);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Correct1" sender:self];
}

else
{
            __errorlabel.text = @"Wrong Answer";


}

 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

  @end
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
if (_inputfield.text isEqualtoString @"USA")
```

is completely wrong spelled/typed. It must be

```
if ([_inputfield.text isEqualToString:@"USA"])
```

or better

```
if ([self.inputfield.text isEqualToString:@"USA"])
```

and as suggested by Jeremy a case insensitive example:

```
if ([[self.inputfield.text uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"USA"])
```

or

```
if (NSOrderedSame == [self.inputfield.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"USA"])
```

You should definitely look into objective-c basics! A good starting point is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html). More on NSString can be learned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: Something else to consider is if user typed 'usa' as opposed to 'USA'.  Maybe include a case-insensitive comparison in your example.

Comment: what has caused the error? There should be a reason given.

Comment: It just says application paused and: self = Viewcontoller *) 0x0a83fa50

Comment: either you have created a breakpoint (blue arrow in a line) or more probable, there is still some error in your code. Then you'll need to post more details on the error. Try to continue the app.

Comment: How to continue the app

Comment: The debugger has a play button if the app is only paused.

Comment: @user: Volker has given a clear response to the information you provided.  I suggest clarifying your question and including all pertinent information, such as the exact error that you are encountering or else comments will become top chatty.

Comment: The app is still running and when I press play it asks to stop the simulator and restart but then the same error occurres!

Comment: Press again,and maybe again, it should print out the error after some tries. Or disable breakpoints, that should also bring a message in te console since the debugger doesn't step in. Best to ask a new question then referring to this one.